# Pre-drawing a UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

There is information that is only available after drawRect that I need to access when loading a UIView. Is there any way to do a "pre-draw" or offscreen in order to get this information earlier?

Comment: It might be more helpful if you elaborate a little more on exactly what you need that isn't available... are you talking about the graphic context?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is depends very much on **what kind of information** you want to get from the view.

Anyway: You can draw the view’s underlying layer into your own graphics context using `[myView.layer renderInContext:myCtx]`. That’s in the QuartzCore.framework, CALayer.h.